# RxSwift, remove cell with animation

Tags: swift, rx-swift

I have a custom button in a cell, which removes item from observable list.

```
self.searchListViewModel.genericList.value.remove(at: index)
```

All logic works well but I need an animation for deleting cell.Something like this

```
self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [IndexPath(row: index, section: 0)],
with: .fade)
```

but for now if I am trying to use both, app crashes.

Comment: You have to use AnimatableSectionModel for this. Datasource insertion or deletion will be taken care with this. RxDataSources

Comment: Hi Aks
Could you please show an example, of how I should use it, couldnt find any example Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the delay. Here is the example for animatable tableview in rxswift.

```
    enum MySectionItem {

        case a(presentable: APresentable)
        case b(presentable: BPresentable)
        case c(presentable: CPresentable)
    }

    extension MySectionItem: IdentifiableType, Equatable {
        typealias Identity = String

        var identity: Identity {
            switch self {
            case let .a(presentable):
                return presentable.title //Something which can define uniqueness
            case let .b(presentable):
                return presentable.title
            case let .c(presentable):
                return presentable.title
            }
        }
    }
```

For SectionModel also you can do the same.

```
enum MySectionModel {

        case a(title: String, items: [MySectionItem])
        case b(title: String, items: [MySectionItem])
        case c(title: String, items: [MySectionItem])
    }

    extension MySectionModel: AnimatableSectionModelType {
        typealias Item = MySectionItem

        var items: [Item] {
            switch self {
            case let .a(title: _, items: items),
                 let .b(title: _, items: items),
                 let .c(title: _, items: items):

                return items.map { $0 }
            }
        }

        var identity: String {
            switch self {
            case let .a(title: title, items: _),
                 let .b(title: title, items: _),
                 let .c(title: title, items: _):

                return title
            }
        }

        init(original: MySectionModel, items: [Item]) {
            switch original {
            case let .a(title: title, items: _):
                self = .a(title: title, items: items)
            case let .b(title: title, items: _):
                self = .b(title: title, items: items)
            case let .c(title: title, items: _):
                self = .c(title: title, items: items)
            }
        }
    }
```